# How to embed ttf fonts as type 1 font by using LuaLatex or XeLatex

Tags: luatex

When using Latex compiler engine I got PDF with embedded type 1. How I get the same in LuaLatex.

Lualatex:
[image]

Latex:
[image]

Advance thanks for the help..

Comment: if you load the same font in luatex as you use in pdftex it will use the 8bit encodings and the same type1 font in the result, but much of the advantage of luatex and xetex is to use Unicode OpenType fonts?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  Unfortunately, it's pretty much impossible to answer your question for certain without knowing how your fonts are chosen.  We can assume, though, that you're choosing them the same way as in pdftex, which means you'll get the same fonts.  Try selecting OpenType (or TrueType) with `fontspec` instead.

Comment: Sir, I'm using ucs(utf8x) package for XML based pagination(Latex->dvips->PDF). I need define the all Unicodes to LaTex based commands. Type 1 font have only 255 characters so remaining characters are manually adjust using some of characters like accents. For my requirement fonts are Embedded as type 1 instead type 1 (CID) by using LuaLaTeX/XeLaTeX. Please advice.